# C++11 STL way of making trees out of subtrees at compile time?

Tags: c++, tree, stl, compile-time

I have a tree made of vectors.

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    std::vector<Node<T>> children;
};

static const std::vector<Node<int>> tree
{
    { 1, {
        { 2, {
            { 3, {} },
            { 4, {} }
        } },
        { 5, {
            { 6, {} },
            { 7, {} }
        } }
    } },

    { 8, {
        { 9, {} }
    } },
    { 10, {
        { 11, {} }
    } }
};
```

I am happy with this tree construct. It's pure STL so it's safe and easy to understand. But the specifications change, and now I have to expose two trees - this one, and one with a slight variation.

```
static const std::vector<Node<int>> tree2
{
    { 1, {} },

    { 2, {
        { 3, {} },
        { 4, {} }
    } },
    { 5, {
        { 6, {} },
        { 7, {} }
    } },

    { 8, {
        { 9, {} }
    } },
    { 10, {
        { 11, {} }
    } }
};
```

The 2 to 7 subtree moved up a rank, but besides that, it is the same tree, and if the specifications for the first one were to change, so would those for the 2nd one, with the only permanent difference being the 2 to 7 subtree moving up a rank.

This means I shouldn't define these two trees separately - I should define subtrees (in this example, 2 to 7 and 8 to 11), and use these subtrees when defining these two trees.

In non syntaxically correct C++ it would look like:

```
static const std::vector<Node<int>> subtree2to7
{
    { 2, {
        { 3, {} },
        { 4, {} }
    } },
    { 5, {
        { 6, {} },
        { 7, {} }
    } }
};

static const std::vector<Node<int>> subtree8to11
{
    { 8, {
        { 9, {} }
    } },
    { 10, {
        { 11, {} }
    } }
};

static const std::vector<Node<int>> tree
{
    { 1, subtree2to7 }
    + subtree8to11
};

static const std::vector<Node<int>> tree2
{
    { 1, {} }
    + subtree2to7
    + subtree8to11
};
```

This is easy dynamically using the likes of `insert`. But I'm curious - what about compile-time ? How could I achieve this kind of tree construction then with minimal custom code and loss of readability ?

For the record I'm not particularly attached to `std::vector` - any iterable container will do. A C++11 solution would be ideal but I'm interested in more modern ways as well.

Comment: Create a concate function?

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved at compile time without maybe some kind of horrible `#include` hacks. But you could do this at *static initialization time* using initialization functions (or llambdas).

Comment: @Galik: Even the redundant, explicit version is not compile-time since `std::vector` is not constexpr (enough, at least until C++23), which just makes you more right.

Comment: @Galik This does the job just fine indeed. I shouldn't have been so specific about compile time. Thanks ! And yeah, regarding `std::vector`, that's why I specified I was fine with other containers.